# Copy text from a row and paste into "the neighbor" row of another column when contenteditable is true

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-composition-api

current result: when I click a row, it fills the entire row of another column rather than single row of another column

```
<p
  class="p-of-that"
  v-html="thatText"
  contenteditable
  @click="writeThat(myArr, $event)"
></p>
```

It should be "kind of" like this when I click one of That's row

[image]

the same thing applies to "Johan". When the given row is clicked, "Johan" appears and "Michael" text is persisted

this is the reproduction: https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-dirac-mk3sk

click a row inside "That" column

---

I hope it fits the bigger picture

Comment: Can you elaborate more, what specific thing you want to achieve?

Comment: have you checked out the codesandbox?

Comment: Yes, but clicking a row in the `That` section lets me type in that row and I think it works fine.

Comment: yea. but beforehand, I apologize if my question makes you confuse. you should see the text is pasted to the entire row of That column. however what I want is it should fill "the neighbor" row of That column. I hope you understand what "the neighbor row" means

Comment: I am quite confused, can you please add some image of what you want?

Comment: when you click a row inside the That column, the text in This column is copy-pasted into the That column you've clicked. but currently it fills the entire row of That column instead

Comment: for example if you click the row which has "Michael" in This column, it should fill the That's row "Michael", only in that particular row

Comment: I've edited my post. so you can understand it better

Comment: Thank You for updating the question, now I understood what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I will solve your issue. But I'm going to try to give you an idea. First of all, you need to think in an array of 2 dimensions. For example:

```js
const myTable = [
    [myObject1, myObject2],
    [myObject3, myObject4]
];
```

Or an objects with some place to the second column. For example:

```js
const myTable = [
    {
        id, column1, column2
    }
];
```

Then, the click on the second column will make `column2` receive values from `column1`. Finally, you update your array and it's done!

### Applying what I said!

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <table border="1">
      <thead>
        <th>This</th>
        <th>That</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(myArr, index) in myArrs" :key="index">
          <td style="width: 120px">{{ myArr.column1.name }}</td>
          <td style="width: 120px">
            <p class="p-of-that" contenteditable @click="writeThat(index)">
              {{ myArr.column2.name }}
            </p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",

  data: () => ({
    myArrs: [
      {
        column1: { id: 1, name: "Michael" },
        column2: { id: 1, name: "" },
      },
      {
        column1: { id: 2, name: "Johan" },
        column2: { id: 2, name: "" },
      },
    ],
  }),

  methods: {
    writeThat(index) {
      this.myArrs[index].column2 = this.myArrs[index].column1;
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

When clicking a row at that time you are passing the complete object to the `writeThat` function, you just need to pass the `myArr.name` in the function instead of passing the whole `myArr`.

Also, add an if condition to check for the current value of `thatText` and the `myArr.name`.

```
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <th>This</th>
        <th>That</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr v-for="myArr in myArrs" :key="myArr.id">
            <td style="width: 120px">{{ myArr.name }}</td>
            <td style="width: 120px" @click="writeThat(myArr.name, $event)" contenteditable>
                <p
                    v-if="thatText === myArr.name"
                    class="p-of-that"
                    v-html="thatText"
                ></p>
             </td>
         </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Also when handling the call for `writeThat`, update the value of `thatText` like:

```
const writeThat = (data, e) => {
    thatText.value = data
    console.log(e);
};
```

Comment: good input. I have to click the row twice tho to make the contenteditable true. The UX is not smooth. Thanks anyway

Comment: I think it needs twice click to make contenteditable to true as the click event is been shifted to the td tag from p tag

Comment: Moving the contenteditable to td tag will solve the issue.

Comment: sorry. I've misinformed you. I've edited my question

Comment: Means you want to persist the data once entered.

Comment: yes. I'm mistaken by saying Michael disappears. it should be persisted when it's blurred